# Accessing files from different applications - Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I have a question regarding accessing data from another application.

I need access to files that are inside another, already installed, application on iPhone so they can be uploaded via REST POST method.
When we tried testing this with simple picker [`FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();]` and navigating to the other application we got something along the lines of 'access denied' message.

We've done this on Android while using Android.App.Application.Context(StartActivity and StartActivityForResault) and Intents (ActionGetContent).

I've read a few articles on Accessing data from another application but I did not fully understand the concept of 'application sandbox'.

Is it even possible? If so, can you give me an example or link to follow so I can see how it's done?

Comment: Generally, no.  This would be a horrible security issue if an app could just read data from other apps.  It is possible for one app to share data with another app.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how is data sharing done?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a try with [Xamarin.Essentials: Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/share?tabs=ios) to share data between apps.

**Files**:

```
var fn =  "Attachment.txt";
var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
File.WriteAllText(file, "Hello World");

await Share.RequestAsync(new ShareFileRequest
{
    Title = Title,
    File = new ShareFile(file)
});
```